# ngrx one request in flight at a time

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

**Context:** Angular 4.x, RxJs 5.4.x, NgRx 4.1.1.

**Goal:** I want to avoid repeating the same api call when multiple components request the same data. I don't want to cancel in-flight requests, just not make future ones till the in-flight one is complete.

**Method:** In the store there is a flag named `isFetching`. In my effect I check the flag to see if there is an in-flight request for already. If so then I don't make the request. The same action that triggers the effect sets the `isFetching` flag to true.

**Problem:** The state is updated before effects are run. So `isFetching` is true before the first request is sent. So no request is ever sent.

**Example:** Here is a simplified version of the problem:

*state.ts*

```ts
export interface State {
    isFetching: boolean;
}
```

*reducer.ts*

```ts
export function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH':
            return <State>{ isFetching: action.payload };
    }

    return state;
}
```

*effect.ts*

```ts
@Effect()
public fetch: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType('FETCH')
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.isFetching), (_, x) => x)
    .filter(x => !x)
    .switchMap(action =>
        this.api.getData()
        .map(data => new FetchSuccess(data))
        .catch(() => Observable.of(new FetchFailure()))
    );
```

**Idea #1:**

I can duplicate the state by keeping a variable in the class that contains the effect. I would set it when the api request was made and use it to filter out future requests.

*effect.ts*

```ts
public isFetching = false;

@Effect()
public fetch: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType('FETCH')
    .filter(() => !this.isFetching)
    .switchMap(action => {
        this.isFetching = true;
        return this.api.getData()
            .map(data => new FetchSuccess(data))
            .catch(() => Observable.of(new FetchFailure()))
            .do(() => this.isFetching = false);
    });
```

**Idea #2:**

Don't have the `'FETCH'` action set `isFetching`. Have the effect emit two actions. The first (`IsFetching`) sets the state and the second (`FetchSuccess | FetchFailure`) is the result. I don't like that I need two actions to do what I feel I should be able to do with one. The advantage is that if there are multiple `'FETCH'` requests there will only be one state update from the `IsFetching` action.

It seems that the results of the effect are applied to state asynchronously. So sequential synchronous `'FETCH'` actions will trigger an equivalent number of requests before the flag is set in state. So don't use this solution.

*effect.ts*

```ts
@Effect()
public fetch: Observable<Action> = this.actions.ofType('FETCH')
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.isFetching), (_, x) => x)
    .filter(x => !x)
    .switchMap(action =>
        this.api.getData()
            .map(data => new FetchSuccess(data))
            .catch(() => Observable.of(new FetchFailure()))
            .startWith(new IsFetching(true))
    );
```

**Question**
Is there a more elegant/standard way to accomplish my goal? Ideally I would like to avoid keeping the same state information in two places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use an operator that maintains its own state.

For example, you could use `distinct`, which accepts a second parameter that clears the operator's internal state upon emission:

```ts
@Effect()
public fetch: Observable<Action> = this.actions
    .ofType('FETCH')
    .distinct(() => 'FETCH', this.actions.ofType(
        'FETCH_SUCCESS',
        'FETCH_FAILURE'
    ))
    .switchMap(action => this.api.getData()
        .map(data => new FetchSuccess(data))
        .catch(() => Observable.of(new FetchFailure()));
    );
```

If the key selector always returns the same value, any `FETCH` actions received whilst one is being handled will be ignored.

Comment: Very creative answer. I had been focused on checking the boolean. I hadn't even considered listening for the event.

Comment: btw, ofType uses a rest parameter so you could shorten it to  `this.actions.ofType('FETCH_SUCCESS', 'FETCH_FAILURE')` and remove the `Observable.Merge`